# How to get object from database when user submits specific key. Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

The procedure follows:

The user fills in an ID, then check if the ID exists in the database. If it exists, create an object then redirect to its show page.

```
# peoples_controller.rb
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  def validate
    @person = Person.find(params[:identity])
    if not @person.blank?
      redirect_to person_path(@person)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Unique identity does not exist"
      render 'index'
    end
  end

end

# routes.rb
root 'people#index'
resources :people
match 'validate', to: 'people#validate', :via => 'get'

# index.html.erb
<%= form_for validate_path, method: :get do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :identity, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Unique ID' %>
    <%= f.submit "Validate", class: "btn btn-block" %>
<% end %>
```

Database table `:people`

[image]

---

So when I fill in the form at `index.html.erb` and click the submit i.e `validate`,

[image]

the URL changes from `http://localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:3000/?%2Fvalidate%5Bidentity%5D=100&commit=Validate`.

> **Expectations:** Go to show view, `render show.html.erb`

Here are the logs

```
Started GET "/?%2Fvalidate%5Bidentity%5D=100&commit=Validate" for ::1 at 2021-04-20 16:53:42 +0800
Processing by PeopleController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"/validate"=>{"identity"=>"100"}, "commit"=>"Validate"}
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering people/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered people/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 744)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered shared/_notices.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 55)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 8.0ms | Allocations: 4119)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 9.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4565)
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you receive `"/validate"` instead of directly `identity`? I got lost, didn't get the question.

Comment: I finally solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it. Use `form_with` instead of `form_for`

```
# index.html.erb
<%= form_with url: validate_path, method: :get do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```